# Como fixar navbar com dropdown?

Tags: html, css

Quero um navbar com menu dropdown e fixo no topo, mas só consigo deixar fixo ou com dropdown funcionando, segue o código:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
    }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; // Se eu tirar essa parte o dropdown funciona
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<...>
```

Se eu tirar o "position: fixed;" dropdown funciona, mas não fica fixo no topo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema não é com o `position:fixed`, é com o `overflow:hidden`

Veja no exemplo que bastou tirar o overflow que ficou tudo certo

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */ /* remova esse overflow */
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="height:2000px; width:100px">
</div>
```